# FFMpeg batch convert video files hangs

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I have some .avi file contains video encoded in h264, and I would like to change to .mp4 and change the rates if needed. You can see the code used to convert below. My problem is that ffmpeg will hang when I try to convert all files, and the file it hangs changes from time to time, I wonder why? Below the code is the output where ffmpeg hangs. I'm running under windows 10, python 2.7.

```
import subprocess
import os

def convert(fileName):
    sourceFile = fileName
    print sourceFile.split('.')
    targetFile = fileName.split('.')[0] + ".mp4"
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', sourceFile, '-r',
         '30000/1001', '-b:a', '2M', '-bt', '4M', '-vcodec',
          'libx264', '-pass', '1', '-coder', '0', '-bf', '0',
           '-flags', '-loop', '-wpredp', '0', '-an', targetFile])



# Set the directory you want to start from
def convertBatch(rootDir = '.'):
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)

        for fname in fileList:
            if fname.endswith(".avi"):
                convert('%s/%s' % (dirName,fname))
                #os.remove('%s/%s' % (dirName,fname))


convertBatch("F:\\data\\mp4")
```

---

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'filename.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 611 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (x264 / 0x34363278), yuv420p, 1024x1024, 578 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) specified for output file #0 (F:\data\mp4_1_16\11\14\512/11_14_512_16.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[libx264 @ 00000000028e42c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 00000000028e42c0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 00000000028e42c0] 264 - core 148 r2721 72d53ab - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=18 lookahead_threads=6 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0000000002bd00a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, mp4, to 'filename.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1024x1024, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Comment: I sometime's wonder why, too, however this question seems pretty vague. Can you reliably reproduce the error? If not I'd say it's the computer gnomes, wreaking havoc with their magic, but also see: https://superuser.com/questions/250155/ffmpeg-hangs-when-creating-a-video

Comment: yeah, I've tried many times, with different numbers of files. When file count is low, every thing works fine, it hangs when file count is large. Generally I think resource shouldn't be a problem since my files are relatively small(just I have a lot of them). I'll go verify about the resource usage. Thank for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ffmpeg flag `-pass 1`

After trial and error, I found the problem is in the ffmpeg flag `-pass 1`, I think(didn't do research) it's because ffmpeg will write statistic data to the same file. And that will cause conflict?